# JPA -@Onetomany and composite keys

Tags: java, jpa

I have two entities :
Destination(key id1,key id2dept and non-key name1) 
and Service(key id3 and non-key name2).

When I generate Schema with OneToMany in `Service` with Target->`Destination`

```
@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)          
private Collection<Destination> d;
```

I receive a Join table with only two keys: Joinedtable(key id3,key id1)
I expected Joinedtable(key id3,key id1,key id2)

With SQL knowledge of JOIN I understand if i join based on id1 = id3,then i should receive
Joinedtable(id1 , id2dept).
But do not receive even that, where are am I going wrong?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BHU_DST")
public class TMP_Destb implements Serializable {
private long id1; 
private long id2dept; 
private char name;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;        
//getter and setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BHU_SVC")
public class TMP_Servb implements Serializable {
private long id2; 
private char name2;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)          
private Collection<TMP_Destb> d;
//getter and setters
}

public class TMP_DestinationPK  implements Serializable {      
private long id1;         
private long id2dept;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//getters setters and hashcodes
}

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"      
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd">
<entity class="mypkg.jpa1.TMP_Destb" access="FIELD">
    <id-class class="TMP_DestinationPK"/>
    <attributes>
        <id name="id1">
        </id>
        <id name="id2dept">
        </id>
    </attributes>
</entity>
<entity class="mypkg.jpa1.TMP_Servb" access="FIELD">
    <attributes>
        <id name="id2">
        </id>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

Comment: What did you expect to get?

Comment: I expected Joinedtable(key id3,key id1,key id2). I am new to this.Help me please

Comment: Provide `Destination` and `Service` beans code.

Comment: You need to provide `@JoinColumn(name="COLUMN_NAME")` as well.

Comment: This link will be helpful [JPA Joins](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany).

Comment: @Ambrish : i require joined table bhu_SVC_bhu_DST with all the keys, id1,id2dept and id2 .Is this possible? or should i create a new entity for this?

Comment: There is an example in the link Ambrish provided that shows how to define the joinColumns used in your relation table.  The entity you have shown does not seem to have an ID mapping defined or shown; it seems like TMP_Destb should have two of them, one on id1 and on id2dept.  This then means you need two join columns defined on relations to this entity, see the example with 'joinColumns' and just add a joinColumn for each of your primary keys.